# Query for records which have date within this month or next month of any year

Tags: soql

I am looking to get all accounts which have Last_Opp_Date__c fall within THIS_MONTH or NEXT_MONTH of any year.

Here is the query i have written

```
select Id,Name,Shipping_Address_Latitude__c,Shipping_Address_Longitude__c,Shipping_Address_Accuracy__c,Last_Opp_Amount__c,Last_Opp_Date__c,Last_Activity_Date__c FROM Account WHERE  Status__c ='Prospect' AND (CALENDAR_MONTH(Last_Opp_Date__c) = THIS_MONTH OR CALENDAR_MONTH(Last_Opp_Date__c) = NEXT_MONTH)
```

This is the error I am getting which means that the calendar month is expecting a number

```
> ='Prospect' AND (CALENDAR_MONTH(Last_Opp_Date__c) = THIS_MONTH OR ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:252 value of filter criterion for expression
> CALENDAR_MONTH(Last_Opp_Date__c) must be of type integer and should
> not be enclosed in quotes
```

Any thoughts on how to get the records that fall within this month or next month of any year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need to use Calendar_Month function.

```
SELECT Id,Name,Shipping_Address_Latitude__c,Shipping_Address_Longitude__c,
Shipping_Address_Accuracy__c,Last_Opp_Amount__c,Last_Opp_Date__c,Last_Activity_Date__c FROM Account WHERE  Status__c ='Prospect' 
AND (Last_Opp_Date__c = THIS_MONTH OR Last_Opp_Date__c = NEXT_MONTH)
```

Refer [Date Formats and Date Literals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm)

- THIS_MONTH - Starts 00:00:00 on the first day of the month that the current day is in and continues for all the days of that month.

`SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE CreatedDate < THIS_MONTH`

- NEXT_MONTH - Starts 00:00:00 on the first day of the month after the month that the current day is in and continues for all the days of that month.

`SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE CloseDate = NEXT_MONTH`

Answer (score 2):

`CALENDAR_MONTH`expects an Integer, so you need to compare it actually to the month numbers.

```
Integer this_month = Date.today().month();
Integer next_month = (this_month == 12)?1:this_month+1;
List<Account> accts = [SELECT ID 
                       FROM Account 
                       WHERE CALENDAR_MONTH(CreatedDate) = :this_month OR          
                             CALENDAR_MONTH(CreatedDate) = :next_month];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
By iterating for loop, we can get the records which have date either in 
current month or next month irrespective of any year - 

List<Position__c> li = [select Close_Date__c from Position__c];
List<Position__c> finalList = new List<Position__c>();
Integer month = System.today().month();
Integer nextMonth = month+1;
System.debug('month is '+month);
for(Position__c pos : li){
    if(pos.Close_Date__c != null && (pos.Close_Date__c.month() == month || 
       pos.Close_Date__c.month() == nextMonth) ){
       finalList.add(pos); 
    }
}
System.debug('test finalList is '+finalList);
```